# converting to JSON Stringify

Tags: json, ajax, datatables, stringify

I am working on data tables server side processing  . In my ajax call I am sending some data and then changing some values on next call of pagination.

this my ajax call code in datatable,

```
"ajax": {
    url: "getBasicCallAnalysisData.json",
    data: function(d) {
        return $.extend({}, d, {
            "newRequest": newReq,
            "totalRecords": total,
            "phone": anumber,
            "from_date": startdate,
            "to_date": enddate
        });
    },
    type: "POST",
    error: function() {
        alert("error");
    },
    complete: function(data) {
        total = data.responseJSON.recordsTotal;
        newReq = 0;
        test(total, newReq);
        $("#loading_image").hide();
        $(".show_datatable").show();
    }
}
```

In my data attribute I need to convert the returned values in `JSON.stringify` because on server side it handles the `strings` not `JSON` objects.

I am using this but it is not working using [link](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data):

```
return JSON.stringify({}, d, {
                            "offset": 0,
                            "newRequest": newReq,
                            "totalRecords": total,
                            "lookInCol": "aNumber",
                            "lookInVal": anumber,
                            "fromDate": startdate,
                            "toDate": enddate
                        });
```

Any idea, how can I convert the `function(d)` returned values into strings and then pass it to the data attribute ?

Comment: are you saying your server takes a single string in JSON format as input? Or you mean each of the fields (newRequest, totalRecords etc) must be a string separately?

Comment: @ADyson please see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/292pnj6r/) . I need response as the jsonstr in the fiddle

Comment: that fiddle doesn't work. Some values are undefined. So I can't see what you mean.

Comment: please see now [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/292pnj6r/1/)

Comment: At a guess would `data: function(d) {
        return JSON.stringify($.extend({}, d, {
            "newRequest": newReq,
            "totalRecords": total,
            "phone": anumber,
            "from_date": startdate,
            "to_date": enddate
        }));
    }` solve your problem?

Comment: ok just seen your edit. define "not working"? What exactly goes wrong?